# Deploy whatsapp-web bot on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, server

I'm creating a whatsapp bot using the node library whatsapp-web.js After I'm done with the script it looks something like  (I just put a overview of the orignal script) -

index.js

```
const {Client, LocalAuth, MessageMedia } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');


const client = new Client({
  puppeteer: {
    args: ['--no-sandbox', "--disable-setuid-sandbox"]
  },
  authStrategy: new LocalAuth()
});
  
client.on('qr', (qr) => {
  console.log('qr received: ', qr);
qrcode.generate(qr, {small:true});
});
  
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('READY');
});

client.on('message', async msg => {
  let type = msg.type;
  let chat = await msg.getChat();
  if(chat.isGroup) {
    //do something
  }else {
    //
    if(msg.body === "ping") {
      msg.reply("pong");
    }
  }
});
```

Everything is fine with the script and it works good on linux or ubuntu  (I already added puppeteer build pack on that Heroku app). As I need to run that script continuously I decided to put that on a worker process.

Procfile

worker: node index.js
But now the problem comes in role, how can I authenticate here? I decided to remove that line from index.js

qrcode.generate(qr,{small:true});
And insted I thought I will print all the logs on heroku-cli

heroku logs -a wweb-bot
#my app named as wweb-bot
and from there access the key generated as qr. After that I'll turn it into a qrcode and scan it. When I did all setup and try it I was getting a continuously generating logs of qr keys. It's nonstop, and keep generating keys after every 15-20 sec. What's the problem here? Is it because Heroku has a **read only** environment or anything else is missing? Please help me how can i do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: now whatsapp-web.js added new functionality of doing this called **RemoteAuthStatergy** just go throughout it.

Comment: Hi, can you explain this?

Comment: Sorry, i mistakenly said "heroku" instead of "wwebjs". Whatever, just go to the doc of wwebjs there should be RemoteAuth in details. It's kinda same as LocalAuth but on a remote server, where it creates and saves data on that server(MongoDB) and does authentication using this automatically everything, upvote if it's helpful : )

Answer (score 0):

remove or comment this code

// authStrategy: new LocalAuth()

it will not work on heroku
but as the code is on server, you don't need to scan again and again, you need to scan only you restart your server

but if you are facing puppeteer error then add these buildpacks in heroku /your project/settings/ scrol down to adduildpack
add these two buildpacks

1. https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack
2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome

then redeploy your app

Comment: But heroku restarts it's server every 24 hours. That's how the authentication again and again word comes

Answer (score 0):

Tried it on Render, Firebase functions and Google Cloud run. Couldn't do it. Had to use a google vm instance at last.